# How to edit intermediate table Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So i'm trying to make 2 models like so

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    availability = models.ManyToManyField(Store)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

and the problem is somewhere in database i need to store amount of concrete goods containing in each store. Like Product#1 - Store#1(23), Store#2(12) and etc.

Is there any possibility to store it in intermediate table (from ManyToManyfield) or is there something easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a [**`through=…`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    availability = models.ManyToManyField(Store, through='StoreProduct')

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class StoreProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```